# when should I choose procedure over object-oriented?

Tags: oop

I've heard many times that we make classes and objects to use them over and over. But what if I have a block of code which I'm sure I'm not going to use it again? Should I still follow OOP? Is there any other reason why we should use OOP except from reusing a block of code?

Comment: when you do not have any other option.

Comment: too many reasons.... scripting... functional programming...embedded programming....but if you are using an OO language, then generally there is no reason not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block of code should be used *somewhere*, just leave it in that somewhere; or if the code is self-contained, refactor it into a function / method. You don't need a separate class for a block of code.

OOP is not only about reusing code. It helps with **managing complexity**, which is crucial for large projects.

Comment: I tried hard to apply this object-oriented design to my code, but it just doesn't make sense. I don't know why, maybe just because this is my first time. I have a turn-based game which has a back-end processing hosted on Google App Engine. One task of this script is to get some data which are players decisions, compare them with each other and do some calculation and see who won the turn and then update the records on Database. Well, I'm pretty sure I should use a DB_connect class but what I'm not sure about is what part of the code should be defined as class and what part shouldn't.

Comment: Well I'm learning object-oriented analysis and design and according to it, I have some things which can exactly be defined as classes. The definition of a class perfectly apply to them, they have properties and methods, but what doesn't make sense to me is that I only would use it once, so why should I make it as a class and why not just put them in the code just like a procedure programming? I'm sure that in OOP not every part would be in a class and I'm trying to understand those parts.

Comment: It's perfectly possible for a class to be instantiated and used only once. Think this way: if a block of code is indepdent enought, we put it into a function / method (no matter how many times it is used); the same thing happens to classes: if the some logic is big and self-contained enought to fit in a class, then make a class.

Comment: Having said that, there is no absolute rules or "perfect solutions" in OOP. In the end we need a system that works correctly, even with some flaws in the design. One mistake often made in learning OOP is getting too **theoretical**, spending too much time on the design, missing the real goal: to make it work. And remember that you can (and should) refactor the code as the system evolves.

Answer (score 1):

While language features like classes and interfaces makes certain kinds of code reuse easier to both write and understand later on, most code reuse can be accomplished without using such a language.

Likewise, simply using C++, C#, Java, or any other "object oriented" language too often doesn't lead to the benefits of object oriented programming.

The primary benefit of object oriented programming is the mindset it puts you in as you're designing the code.  If you do it correctly, you start by designing the classes and how they communicate with each other.  The clean interfaces resulting from a good object oriented design might result in code that will be reused by other projects, but usually does not unless that was a goal of your design.

What you gain by such a design, however, is code that is more likely to work, can be more easily tested, and is far easier to understand and maintain in the future.